# Android Canvas - How to redraw at same place with different color

Tags: android

I am drawing a blue circle on the canvas at x,y.

```
mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
mCanvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, mPaint);
```

Now I want to redraw at the same place with red color.

```
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
mCanvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, mPaint);
```

This never succeeds. The circle shown is always blue. What can I do to achieve the red circle in the second drawCircle

Comment: I've never used the android canvas, but in all the "canvas stuff" I've done (most recently HTML5) you need to make sure you "stroke" the cancas to get it to actually draw the stuff it has buffered up. Could that be your problem?

Comment: I checked and my style is mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); Also I am calling invalidate after the paint.

Comment: What happens if you remove the code for drawing the blue circle?

Comment: If I remove the code for blue circle, red circle gets drawn fine.

Comment: you're supposed to call invalidate BEFORE the paint, not after. invalidate makes onDraw fire. It's in onDraw that you want to do the actual drawing.

Comment: Awesome. THat is what I was missing. I had to move them inside onDraw(). Thanks a lot Dr.

Answer (score 0):

In an app I worked on awhile back, I have:

```
ImageView playLayout;
Display display;
Canvas canvas;
Bitmap bitmap;
Paint paint;
```

I then have:

```
display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
screenHeight = playLayout.getHeight();
screenWidth = playLayout.getWidth();
playLayout = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playLayout); //playLayout in xml
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
paint = new Paint();
```

Then in a thread to prevent lag:

```
   paint.setARGB(255, red, green, blue);

   canvas.drawCircle(x, y, circleRadius, paint);
                        playLayout.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                playLayout.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
```

This works for me. The circle does not actually draw, until I call `playLayout.setImageBitmap`.

Let me know if I need me to add more info or anything, and I'll try to help.